# Squirrel.Windows with pre-release tag

Tags: c#, wpf, squirrel.windows

So i just switched from ClickOnce to Squirrel.Windows.
We are creating NuGet packages and getting the version number from GitVersion. We build our develop branch and mark it as a pre-release using the syntax *1.0.0-beta1*. This works great and we can upload other API's to Nuget.org. But we want to use *Squirrel.Windows* to distribute our WPF client with the same versioning schema.

For some reason that does not seem to be working. Any one of you using *Squirrel.Windows* in a similar way and could help us out?

Thanks

- Franklin

Comment: Got this to work...:-)

Comment: can you share how you got the pre-release packages to work with squirrel. It's my understanding that it won't trigger an update based on a bump of the label segment (1.0.1-alpha.1 ==> 1.0.1-alpha.2) - Squirrel would simply ignore anything after 1.0.1.  Is that not the case?